# Generating function for combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> Find the number of possibilities to divide $n$ balls into $3$ cells, such that:

- In the first cell there must be at least one ball.
- No limitations for middle cell.
- In right cell, the number of balls **isn't** dividable by $3$.

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{{1 - x}} \cdot \frac{1}{{1 - x}} \cdot \left( ? \right)$$

The first two are relatively easy. How to convert the third demand into a generating function?

More specifically, What is the power series of:

$$y = (x + {x^2} + {x^4} + {x^5} + ...)$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : Subtract the sequence $x^3+x^6+x^9+...$ from $x+x^2+x^3+...$

Both sequences are geometric.